# How to subtract two columns in Google Sheets query?

Tags: google-sheets-query

I checked the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) but couldn't find a way to subtract two columns from each other.

Imagine you have two columns and you want to construct a query that return the subtraction of those two columns.

Comment: See [aritmethic operators](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#arithmetic-operators)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example with a formula such as:

```
=query(A:B,"select A-B label A-B 'Profit'")
```

[image: WA111211 example]

[QUERY](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)