# sum two grouped columns in Google Sheets QUERY Language

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I want QUERY command to provide me with the sum of two columns, and group the result by Column A.

The following is not working (parsing error)

`=query(Ledger!A2:G,"SELECT A, sum(D+E) where (B = ...) group by A order by A")`

... neither is this (empty results)

`=query(Ledger!A2:G,"SELECT A, sum(D)+sum(E) where (B = ...) group by A order by A ")`

I can, of course, use the query below, and sum the columns using the `=SUM()` command, but I would rather have the query already return the sum of both columns.

`=query(Ledger!A2:G,"SELECT A, sum(D), sum(E) where (B = ...) group by A order by A")`

based on [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/111211/how-to-subtract-two-columns-in-google-sheets-query), and [this](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#arithmetic-operators), my query should be working, but it is not. Why? Any workaround (that does not involve array formulas or using the `=SUM()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sum` clause will not work the way you expect with blank values. To convert the blanks to zeros, use `n()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( query( 
  { Ledger!A2:C, n(D2:E) }, 
  "select Col1, sum(Col4) + sum(Col5) 
   where Col2 = 42 
   group by Col1", 
  0 
) )
```

The `group by` clause sorts the primary column automatically, so an `order by` clause is not needed here.

Another perhaps a simpler way to do the same is to do the math in the array, like this:

```
=arrayformula( query( 
  { Ledger!A2:C, D2:D + E2:E }, 
  "select Col1, sum(Col4) 
   where Col2 = 42 
   group by Col1", 
  0 
) )
```

Comment: Thanks - given the size of my spreadsheet, I am really avoiding arrayformulas as they make calculations really slow

Comment: I do not think there will be any measurable performance difference here. To improve spreadsheet performance, see [these optimization tips](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/102271339?msgid=102278707).